# Tfs Collection Url mismatch. Expected : http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/, Current http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection in TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to configure TestAgent in remote machine via **Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment** Step of Build configuration in vNext build of **TFS 2015**.

Tfs Collection Url mismatch. Expected : **http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/**, Current **http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection**

Its just a **/**

I am getting the below mentioned error

```
Tfs Collection Url mismatch. Expected : http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/, Current http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection. Reconfiguration required.
Trying to open the config file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Ide\DTAExecutionHost.exe.config
Changing trace level...
Logs will now be stored at : C:\DtaLogs
Stdout : Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Test Agent Configuration Tool Version 14.0.24712.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Getting Configuration:
Queried current configuration successfully.
Verify user name and password:
Validated user name and password.
Enable Remote Desktop:
No change to the Remote Desktop setting as Remote Desktop was already enabled on the machine.
Firewall Configuration:
No change to the firewall setting as the firewall exception was already enabled for the service 'Remote Desktop'.
Configured firewall exceptions for: 'Remote Desktop'.
Failed to configure TFS Team Project Collection.
TeamProjectCollection Configuration:
Registered with the team project collection successfully.
Stop test agent process:
Test agent process stopped successfully.
Configure test agent as an interactive process:
Adding the process as startup program for user EA\Administrator...
Disabling screen saver for user EA\Administrator...
Configured test agent process successfully.
ACL Configuration:
Configured ACL successfully.
Start test agent process:
Test agent process started successfully.
Stop Service:
Stopped service.
Service Configuration:
Removed service successfully.
Service Configuration:
Exit code : -1
TestAgent Configuration failed with exit code
Deploy and configuration of test agent failed. Check the logs for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is fixed by updating TFS 2015 Update 1, its a bug with Microsoft TFS 2015 though.

There is no documentation about the bug and it took me lot of time to figure out.

Thanks,